# JavaFx embed Swing JDesktopPane doesn't display anything

Tags: java, swing, javafx-8

I have read and ran with success this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm).

I want to embed internal frames into JavaFX using Swing [JDesktopPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html).

**Code:**

```
public class FxSwingFx extends Application {

   private static void createSwing( SwingNode swingNode ) {
      final JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
      swingNode.setContent( desktopPane );
      final JInternalFrame if1 = new JInternalFrame( "Hello, ", true, true, true, true );
      final JInternalFrame if2 = new JInternalFrame( " World!", true, true, true, true );
      if1        .setVisible( true );
      if2        .setVisible( true );
      desktopPane.setVisible( true );
      desktopPane.add( if1 );
      desktopPane.add( if2 );
   }

   @Override
   public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
      final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
      final BorderPane root = new BorderPane( swingNode );
      root.setBottom( new Button( "FX Button" ));
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createSwing( swingNode ));
      primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 400, 300 ));
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Question**: Why internal frames aren't shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition to see internal frames are:

- A size must be set with `setSize()`, `setPreferredSize()` isn't enougth
- `setVisible( true )` must have been called

**Code:**

```
public class FxSwingFx extends Application {

   JInternalFrame createInternalFrame( String title, int width, int height ) {
      final JInternalFrame frame = new JInternalFrame( title, true, true, true, true );
      frame.setVisible( true );
      frame.setSize( width, height );
      return frame;
   }

   void createSwing( SwingNode swingNode ) {
      final JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
      desktopPane.add( createInternalFrame( "One", 400, 300 ));
      desktopPane.add( createInternalFrame( "Two", 400, 300 ));
      swingNode.setContent( desktopPane );
   }

   @Override
   public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception {
      final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createSwing( swingNode ));
      final BorderPane root = new BorderPane( swingNode );
      final Button jfxBtn = new Button( "FX Button" );
      root.setBottom( jfxBtn );
      primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 600, 500 ));
      primaryStage.show();
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      launch( args );
   }
}
```

**Result:**

[image: JavaFX8 Application with JDesktopPane]